# Dealing with $\delta^{(3)}(0)$ using normal ordering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian, dirac-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

On page 109 of [David Tong's lecture notes on QFT](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf), equations (5.11) and (5.12) read:
$$ H = \int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}} E_{\vec{p}}[(b_{\vec{p}}^{s})^{\dagger}b_{\vec{p}}^{s}-c_{\vec{p}}^{s}(c_{\vec{p}}^{s})^{\dagger}] = \int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}E_{\vec{p}}[(b_{\vec{p}}^{s})^{\dagger}b_{\vec{p}}^{s}-(c_{\vec{p}}^{s})^{\dagger}c_{\vec{p}}^{s} +(2\pi)^{3}\delta^{(3)}(0)].$$
This is the quantized Hamiltonian for the Dirac field. Then, D. Tong says:

> "The $\delta^{(3)}$ term is familiar and easily dealt with by normal ordering."

The definition of normal ordering is given on page 26. An operator is said to be normal ordered if all annihilation operators $a_{\vec{p}}$ is placed to the right.

**Question:** Can someone explain to me what Tong meant with the above quotation? I mean, didn't the normal ordering *caused* the term $\delta^{(3)}(0)$ in the expression of $H$, since we used $[c_{\vec{p}}^{s},(c_{\vec{p}}^{s})^{\dagger}] = (2\pi)^{3}\delta^{(3)}(0)$ to place the $c_{\vec{p}}^{s}$ to the right?

Comment: It looks like you're using a commutator relation for the ladder operators rather than an anticommutator. Remember for fermions this is needed to ensure a positive definite Hamiltonian

Comment: @fewfew4 yeah, nice catch! But Tong uses commutation relations before anticommutation relations to motivate the latter. This is the same approach as Peskin & Schroeder.

Answer (score 0):

Normal ordering for fermions does the following to $c_{p}^sc_{p}^{s\dagger}$:
$$N(c_{p}^sc_{p}^{s\dagger})=-c_{p}^{s\dagger}c_{p}^{s}$$
and leaves the product $b_{p}^{s\dagger}b_{p}^{s}$ unchanged. So the normal ordered Hamiltonian is
$$N(H)=N\Big(\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}E_p(b_{p}^{s\dagger}b_{p}^{s}-c_{p}^sc_{p}^{s\dagger})\Big)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}E_p\big(N(b_{p}^{s\dagger}b_{p}^{s})-N(c_{p}^sc_{p}^{s\dagger})\big)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}E_p(b_{p}^{s\dagger}b_{p}^{s}+c_{p}^{s\dagger}c_{p}^{s})$$
So the infinite dirac delta function contribution never appears in the normal ordered Hamiltonian. The expression you have was obtained by rewriting $H$ in terms of the normal ordered operators $b_{p}^{s\dagger}b_{p}^{s}$ and $c_{p}^{s\dagger}c_{p}^{s}$, but this is not the same as the normal ordered $N(H)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, you are basically saying that the normal ordering is not the same as using the commutation/anticommutation relations to place the annihilation operator to the right, right? The normal ordering is just replacing it to the right, by definition. However, how does this deals with the delta problem?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The delta $\delta^3(0)$ only appears when you reorder things using the commutation relations. As you can see by the delta does not appear in $N(H)$, hence no infinite additive term.

Comment: Oh, Now I think I got it. What Tong meant is that one does not need to use the commutation relation as he did; instead, one can rearrange the operators by using normal ordering so to avoid the inclusion of a delta function. Seems correct?